# The Select/Unselect all are not working in Kartik select2 yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

**I have selecting, unselect and unselecting event. But when I click on select all or unselect all none of these events are called.**
Every thing is working find except the select/Unslect all issue.Here is my code

```
            echo $form->field($model, 'partnersIn')->widget(Select2::class, [
                'name'          => 'partnersIn[]',
                'data'          => Partner::PartnersData(),
                'theme'         => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                'options'       => ['value' => $partners, 'placeholder' => Yii::t(
                    'app',
                    'Select the partners to show ad'
                )],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                     'tags' => true,
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'multiple'   => true,
                ],
            ])->label('Partners');
            ?>
```

[image]

Comment: any errors in console when you click on i t?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no any javascript or jquery error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the composer update or composer install command.
Its work for me